# Excel macro: issue with removal off rows when conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I am currently working on an Excel-macro that deletes rows in sheetA based on a value or specific text in SheetB and/or SheetC.

However, when multiple cells meet the conditions, not all rows are deleted. Therefore, I need to run the macro multiple times.

Is there a way to delete all rows for which the conditions are met, independent of the number of rows the macro will have to delete?

My current code:

```
Sub Delete_rows()
    Dim Rev As Worksheet 
    Dim Acc As Worksheet 
    Dim OFE As Worksheet
    
    Set Acc = Worksheets("Outstanding Accruals") 
    Set Rev = Worksheets("Reversals") 
    Set OFE = Worksheets("Output for Exact")
    
    For i = 2 To Acc.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If OFE.Cells(i, 11).Value <> 0 Then
            If OFE.Cells(i, 9).Value Like "Reversal*" Then
                OFE.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
        
        If OFE.Cells(i, 11).Value <> 0 Then
            If OFE.Cells(i, 9).Value Like "Reversal*" Then
                OFE.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete             
            End If
    
        If Rev.Cells(i, 14).Value = "Yes " Then
            Acc.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            Rev.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        
        If Rev.Cells(i, 14).Value = "Yes " Then
            Acc.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            Rev.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's always a good idea to delete from the end to the start: `For i =Acc.UsedRange.Rows.Count to 2 Step -1` as the order of the rows doesn't get messed up.